# Error when running yarn command cannot find module

Tags: javascript, windows, yarnpkg

Error with yarn has happened on my windows machine. I installed yarn using choco and saw this error. I am trying to install yarn version 1.22.15 I am on node 17.0.1. I also tried updating my system env variables as well to point to the binary file. Also tried restarting my windows powershell as well.
[image]